# React Native Android: ./gradlew assembleRelease breaks with haul

Tags: android, react-native, apk, gradlew

I'm using [haul](https://github.com/callstack-io/haul) as my development server/bundler for a React Native app I am building because I need access to sym links and the standard React Native bundler doesn't give access to them.

I followed the documentation and added:

```
project.ext.react = [
    cliPath: "node_modules/haul/bin/cli.js"
]
```

to my `android/app/build.gradle` file and generated the following `wepack.haul.js` file.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = ({ platform, root }, defaults) => {
    return {
      entry: `./index.${platform}.js`,
      resolve: {
          ...defaults.resolve,
          alias: {
              ...defaults.resolve.alias,
              config: path.join(root, 'config.js')
          }
      }
    }
};
```

When I run `./gradlew assembleRelease` in the android folder of my project directory to generate the .apk file, I get the following error that it couldn't follow the symbolic link.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not list contents of '/Users/brendan/Projects/<project-name>/node_modules/<team-name>/mart-redux/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/.bin/nopt'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

I'm also getting error messages that my config alias in my webpack.haul file isn't resolving but I believe both of these issues are related.

I believe that the `./gradlew assembleRelease` call is using the standard RN packager rather than haul which is why the sym links and alias resolve aren't working properly.

How can I get `./gradlew assembleRelease` to use haul?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to solve the issue but I got haul working in both my local environment and building the .apk file by commenting out the line below in the `android/app/build.gradle`.

```
 project.ext.react = [
     cliPath: "node_modules/haul/bin/cli.js"
 ]

 // apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```